# Full screen video, supporting all browsers

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, html5-video

Can you help me with full screen video play, with pause, supporting all the browsers like www.rotary.org I could play video in chrome and mozilla. It is not played in Safari.
When I'm using video.js, it shows error message in safari.

```
<head> <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.8.8/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"> <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script></head><body><video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"poster="image.png" data-setup="{}">
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
<source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogv">
<source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
<p class="vjs-no-js">
    To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
    <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
</p></video><script src="scripts/video.js"></script></body>
```

Comment: More context will help you get better answers. For instance try adding a code block with a minimal example of what you have tried so far and a description of how that fits in with your larger environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the [Video.js](http://videojs.com/) a few times which seems to have excellent browser compatibility.

Comment: When I tried using this, in Safari it shows error "The media could not be loaded, ...." is there any solution to solve this?